# Cannot update to Null error when calling entityManager.remove?

Tags: java, oracle, entitymanager, sqlexception

I am attempting to remove an entity and delete its row from the database using the following method:

```
public void remove(Object o){
        this.persistence.entityManager().remove(o);
    }
```

When I attempt to do so I am getting the error:

```
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCHEMA"."TABLE"."COLUMN") to NULL
```

I know that there is a `IS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT` on this column.

But *why* would this matter if the row is going to be deleted? I do not understand why I am getting this error?

Comment: Are you sure it's the entity you are removing, and not a parent/child relationship? Perhaps an orphan?

Comment: because (i'm guessing here) the error comes from a foreign key constraint, ie the key pointing to the row you are trying to delete cannot be set to null

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am removing any child relationships first?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ please explain further?

Comment: @java123999 why are you asking me? I didn't write your code. I don't know what cascades you have on the DB or in JPA itself.

Comment: Ok, is it not possible to carry out this deletion without removing the constraint?

Comment: Of course it is. You just need to respect the constraints that you yourself have imposed. If you have required that `parent_id` on a child is `NOT NULL` and you delete the `Parent`, then Hibernate will update the `parent_id` to `NULL` - called "orphaning". This will cause the delete to fail; and with good reason. You need to understand what it is that you are deleting and the impact that has; as well as what cascade means - both at the JPA level and at the SQL level.